# Importing existing Android project from github that uses Google Maps API, Google Authentication fails

Tags: android, eclipse, github, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm new to using github, but I am somewhat positive I have it configured in eclipse properly.

I'm also new to using the Google Maps API. However, the other people working on the project already have it configured with the API key and it works for them.

In my case, however:

The project successfully imports. When I run the app on my nexus 7 through eclipse, the app runs.

When the google maps api is called, the map opens but it without any map data (blank).

The console is showing a Google Authentication error.

Do I have to use my own API key?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the API key is hardcoded in the AndroidManifest.xml in the project: ask one of the others developers to give you debug keystore from their `~/.android/` (`C:\Users\somename\.android\` on Windows) folder and put it in the same location on your machine.